# How to nest widgets dynamically in flutter dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to build nested widgets such that initially there will be one group with one sub-group. Then on click of the add sub-group button it will add sub-groups. Also I should be able to delete the clicked delete button of the sub-group. Also I have a add group button which will add the groups. I have added the following code but it adds sub group to all the sub groups of the groups.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

My code:

```
ListView.builder(
    shrinkWrap: true,
    itemCount: _groupCount,
    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
      var removeWidget = Container(
        height: 100,
        width: 50,
      );
      if (index > 0) {
        removeWidget = Container(
          height: 100,
          width: 100,
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                child: OutlinedButton(
                  style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
                    foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    debugPrint("Remove Group clicked");
                    setState(() {
                      if(_groupCount>1)
                        --_groupCount;
                    });
                  },
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.delete,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
      return Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            children: [
              Container(
                height:40,
                width: 100,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Padding(
                      padding:
                      EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 10.0, 0.0, 10.0),
                      child:
                      Text("Item #" + (index+1).toString() + " Add"),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),

          Container(
            height:  100,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Row(
                  children: [
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 100,
                      width: 200,
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        children: const [
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                            child: TextField(
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                labelText: 'formfield1',
                                hintText: 'formfield1',
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 100,
                      width: 200,
                      child: Column(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                            child: OutlinedButton(
                              style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
                                foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                                backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                              ),
                              onPressed: () {
                                debugPrint("Add sub group clicked");
                                ///add sub group
                                setState(() {
                                  _subGroupCount++;
                                });
                              },
                              child: Text("Add sub-Group"),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                    removeWidget
                  ],
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: _subGroupCount,//_groupItemCount,
                // physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return
                    Container(
                      height:  100,
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          Row(
                            children: [
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 100,
                                width: 200,
                                child: Column(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                    Padding(
                                      padding:
                                      EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 8.0, 0.0, 8.0),
                                      child: TextField(
                                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                                          labelText: 'Sub group field1',
                                          hintText: 'Sub group field1',
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                              SizedBox(
                                height: 100,
                                width: 200,
                                child: Column(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                  children: [
                                    Padding(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                                      child: OutlinedButton(
                                        style: OutlinedButton.styleFrom(
                                          foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                                          backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                                        ),
                                        onPressed: () {
                                          if(_subGroupCount>1) {
                                            debugPrint("Remove sub-group clicked");
                                            ///remove  sub-group
                                            setState(() {
                                              _subGroupCount--;
                                            });
                                          }
                                          else
                                          {
                                            debugPrint("Add Items clicked");
                                            ///add items
                                            setState(() {
                                              _subGroupCount++;
                                            });
                                          }
                                        },
                                        child: Icon( (_subGroupCount>1) ? Icons.delete : Icons.edit ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    );
                }),
          ),
        ],
      );
    }),
```

Screenshots attached for more clearity:

[image: screenshot 1]

[image: screenshot 2]

[image: screenshot 3]

I tried using the `ListView.builder` I don't know exactly how to build the logic. Also is there any way to do using maps in Flutter?

Comment: so i will have to do changes in the core files of the flutter framework to make it work as per my needs? thats what you are suggesting me?
By the way thanks for your response :)

Comment: Use ListView.builder and inside that return your group element. Define count variable outside build() and increment it on click of add. And set Listview.builder count to this count variable

Comment: Hi Prashant i have implemented the code what you are trying to say, i have defined 2 variables with 1 as initial value and used them as groupcount and subgroupcount while building the listview builder but there are groups and sub-groups in my UI so when i click on add group it should add 1 group with 1 subgroup by default under that group, once i click on any of the add subgroup button it should add subgroup to that particular group only, how can we identify that group and add subgroup to that group only?